# WSL2 couldnt find .wslconfig file in windows 11

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to set a bridged connection between WSL and windows 11 to get the same ip interfaces. after searching online, looks like I need to modify the file `.wslconfig` located in `%Userprofile%` with the following cinfigureaito

But I'm not able to find the `.wslconfi` in the provided path

```
[wsl2]
networkingMode=bridged
vmSwitch=my-switch
ipv6=true
```

Comment: If its not there, _create_ it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create it yourself if it's not there.
It will just look for the file there, no matter if you create it or if it was already there.